# Order of execution in Community LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, community

I am creating records with LWC Form on Community. And I have a Before Trigger on account Object, But the trigger executes after saving into the record. Is there any order of execution for Community or LWC?

Comment: I have rolled back a change to this question because it caused the answer to no longer make sense. If you're not satisfied with the answer you received, please _add_ information to your question rather than removing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trigger order of execution has nothing to do with Communities or LWC because those front end components perform all of their actions prior to start of the trigger order of execution.

The LWC makes an API call, one way or another, to initiate a record create operation. Once that API call begins executing on the server, the [trigger order of execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) is run from top to bottom, including before insert triggers. A before trigger never executes in an after context.

If you need to take action on the record data prior to initiating the save operation, do it in your front-end JavaScript.